# Getting error in "search_read" method for "calendar.event"

Tags: odoo, openerp-8, odoo-8

I am using "search_read" method of model "calendar.event".
I want to fetch records which are generated after specific date.

For that i am passing input parameter as

```
<__NSArrayI 0x7dc080f0>(
DB Name,
1,
username,
calendar.event,
search_read,
(
(
write_date,
>,
2015-05-21 11:06:54
)

)

)
```

But i am getting error as:

**if 'display_time' in fields:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable**

Where i am going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

it is a bug and raises if you have **recurring** calendar events

for recurring events the variable `fields` is empty so you have to modify the code by adding a check at the fields var.

Open the `/PATH-TO-YOUR-ODOO-INSTALLATION/addons/calendar/calendar.py` file and search for

```
if 'display_time' in fields:
```

Change it to

```
if fields and 'display_time' in fields:
```

This should solve the problem